# Erro ao instalar o ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

Como resolver o erro, ao instalar o ionic:

[image: npm install ionic | npm install -g ionic]

Obs.: Utilizo endereço proxy, 10.83.0.234:3128, e mesmo após a configuração do `npm config set proxy meu.endereco.proxy:porta` continua sem funcionar.

Comment: Você instalou o Node.js antes? Alteoru o PATH nas variáveis de ambiente?

Comment: Sim, instalei o nodejs e esse é o final do caminho da variável de ambiente: ;C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%/ AppData/ Roaming/ npm/ node_modules/ @angular/ cli/ bin` e `%USERPROFILE%/ AppData/ Roaming/ npm`.

Tenta usar esses caminhos (sem os espaços)

Comment: Continua o erro. Final do log:
...
101 verbose statusCode 403
102 verbose pkgid superagent-proxy@^2.0.0
103 verbose cwd C:\Users\Administrador
104 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
105 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Administrador\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
106 verbose node v10.16.3
107 verbose npm  v6.10.3
108 error code E403
109 error 403 Forbidden - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/superagent-proxy